# Where does Trace.TraceInformation log data when running an azure worker in the emulator?

Tags: azure

I created a windows azure worker role.  I used the default templates and the default app.config for the worker role.

```
 <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener,      Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                name="AzureDiagnostics">
 </add>
```

The worker role is using Trace.TraceInformation to log messages.

In which file does the information get logged?

Answer (score 8):

Diagnostics data collected by your roles is stored in Windows Azure Storage Tables & Blob Containers. Assuming you have configured diagnostics properly, you should see a table called `WADLogsTable` in a storage account specified via `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString` config setting in your role's `cscfg` file. This is where you will see the data. You may find this link helpful regarding configuring diagnostics for your worker role: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433048.aspx.

Comment: It seems in the latest (early 2017) versions of Azure Diagnostics (in particular, the Azure PaaSDiagnostics Extension - not the plugin) there is no `WADLogsTable`.

Answer (score 6):

If you see just your `TraceError` messages but not your `TraceInformation` then you should change the diagnostics settings of the role in your cloud project.

- Goto your cloud project, select the role in question and properties
- Goto Configuration tab and click Configure button

There you should see under General tab "Select a diagnostic configuration" section.

There you should select **All information** radio button to see `TraceInformation`.

Comment: I found this in my site -> Monitoring -> Diagnostic Logs -> Level

Answer (score 0):

With addition to above step, select Storage account in Configuration tab so that it will get automatically gets added into settings tab under Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString